# What should I consider when purchasing a (flatbed) scanner?

Tags: drivers, scanning, scanner

I'm considering purchasing a new USB flatbed scanner for my parents whose laptop is running Ubuntu (10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx).

Doing a quick search around I found this thread over in the forums: [Lightweight Scanner](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613181) and it seems:

- Generally I should check the [SANE project](http://www.sane-project.org/) to see if a specific scanner will work under Linux.
- [EPSON](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=154806&infoType=Downloads) distributes its own Linux drivers [by Avasys](http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/)
- HP seems to have good Linux support: [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) is already installed with Ubuntu (although for me here it seems that the version with Ubuntu 10.04 isn't the newest one and could need some fiddling when I buy a new HP printer)

What other factors need I take into account when buying a scanner for Ubuntu? Anything specific to some applications (GIMP, etc.)? Will the now-typical scanner buttons to directly scan a PDF document work on some printers and not on others? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have jet to find a scanner, that Ubuntu has no drivers for. Most scanners use a  standardised USB interface similar to other hid devices such as keyboards, mice etc. If you want to be on the safe side choose a scanner mentioned in the SANE project's supported devices list.

As for applications: SANE handles scanners in Ubuntu. They all revert to SANE. You'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks! ... "SANE handels scanners in Ubuntu." ... will the proprietary Epson drivers also refer to SANE?

Comment: I do have a scanner that doesn't have a Ubuntu driver (or at least didn't three years ago when I replaced it).  Personally, I have found HP has some of the best Linux support, so I stick with them.

Comment: I also like hp very much. @Martin: Normally Ubuntu should take care of picking the right driver. If not, follow the instructions that come with the proprietary dirver.

Comment: Yes, Epson scanners (at least V350 model) refer to SANE. Avasys drivers for Epson devices actually install the SANE support files for them.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with HP printer/scanners. My current one, HP Photosmart C4750, works well in Ubuntu. It is connected through WIFI and scans to PDF using hplip. I have used HP flatbed USB with success, also. Follow this link [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html) for additional information. You can install the hplip and hplip-gui through Synaptic. The one odd thing is the hplip-gui is not linked in the application menu but in  System > Preference. Besides scanning hplip will status the device and give info on ink and such. The GUI is easy to use.

hplip has been around for years.

Comment: It's mostly OK for inkjets, but I personally had many strange incompatibilities with old Laserjet 1005 using HPLIP. It installs PPD file, seems like Ubuntu is connecting to HP 1005, yet nothing happens when I try to print from LibreOffice or eVince.

Comment: I've had zero problems. If the printer works well in Ubuntu before it will work well with hplip.

Comment: Yes, I managed to configure my HP1005 in 10.10 very easily, but at this moment I see something strange with HP1005 (it doesn't print, but when I recconect HP1005 to my laptop, it starts printing). I suppose that it may be an issue of HPLIP version or  a matter of HPLIP standalone installation (downloaded from HPLIP site).